# MVC DropDownListFor Bind on Nested Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, dropdownlistfor

Sorry this is probably really obvious but I just need to check. I have a class with nested classes within containing related information. The Class is singular and not in a list or anything yet MVC wont bind to the field.

Model

```
public class Car
{
    public GloveBoxDetail GloveBox = new GloveBoxDetail();
}

public class GloveBoxDetail
{
    public bool isLockable{get;set;}
}
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GloveBox.isLockable, new SelectList(...))
```

Am I going to have to manually create the DropDownList's?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Isn't a drop down list only used for collections? What would be the choices to choose from?

Comment: @gunr2171 Common misconception: Dropdown is used for selecting a single value, not a collection. The collection has to come from somewhere else, which is indicated in the ``new SelectList()`` in his code

Comment: @Kippie, I stand corrected. Thanks.

Comment: How about using a checkbox instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to figure it out last night. Its only for displaying data so updating the model isn't required so I don't need to worry about binding on a post back. I solved it by setting the "Selected Value" of the Select List to the model, dirty but it works.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can bind any IEnumarable to DropDownList

Please try like this

In Controller

```
List<SelectListItem> yesno=new List<SelectListItem>();
yesno.add(new SelectListItem("Yes","Yes",true);
yesno.add(new SelectListItem("No","No");

ViewBag.YesNoList=yesno;
```

in View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GloveBox.isLockable,
      IEnumbarable<SelectListItem>(ViewBag.YesNoList))
```

Its better to use `@Html.CheckboxFor` in this case. If you need `Nullable<bool>` then you may need to create your own Custom Html Helper

Check this post on [creating custom helper](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)